# Connecting the image resizing module in the PrimeVue editor component

Tags: nuxt.js, quill, primevue

I'm attempting to integrate the [Quill Image Resize module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quill-image-resize) with the [Editor](https://primevue.org/editor) component from PrimeVue (v3.50.0) to NuxtJS (v3.10.3) project. Could you please guide me on how to do this correctly?

I've discovered that it can be accomplished through the `:modules` [property](https://primevue.org/editor/#api.editor.props.modules), but I haven't been able to find any information on the exact steps to do so